# How to identify Seekbar change events in Rx?

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-binding

I want to identify Seekbar change events using Rx android. The catch is that I want to identify all the events inside a single observable and not multiple observable. Here is my code snippet which contains the progress change event.

```
 RxSeekBar.userChanges(setup_volume_limit_seekbar)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .skip(1)
            .subscribe {
                var value = it
                if (value == 0) {
                    value = 1
                }
                // More code here
            }
```

All I want to do is listen for stop event when user stops moving his finger over the Seekbar.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So I found the proper solution. It is possible to catch all seekbar callbacks inside one observable itself. Below is the solution

**Kotlin**

```
RxSeekBar.changeEvents(seekbar)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { seekBarChangeEvent ->
            when (seekBarChangeEvent) {
                is SeekBarProgressChangeEvent -> Log.d(TAG, "on Progress : " + seekBarChangeEvent.progress())
                is SeekBarStartChangeEvent -> Log.d(TAG, "on Start : ")
                is SeekBarStopChangeEvent -> Log.d(TAG, "on Stop : ")
            }
        }
```

**Java**

```
RxSeekBar.changeEvents(seekbar)
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(seekBarChangeEvent -> {
            if (seekBarChangeEvent instanceof SeekBarProgressChangeEvent)
            {
                SeekBarProgressChangeEvent seekBarProgressChangeEvent = (SeekBarProgressChangeEvent) seekBarChangeEvent;
                Log.d(TAG, "on Progress : " + seekBarProgressChangeEvent.progress());
            }
            else if (seekBarChangeEvent instanceof SeekBarStartChangeEvent)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "on Start : " );
            }
            if (seekBarChangeEvent instanceof SeekBarStopChangeEvent)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "on Stop : " );
            }
        });
```